# json правка данных

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
[
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27 21:05:11","type":"1","source_id":123},
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27 21:07:37","type":"1","source_id":135},
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27 22:03:33","type":"1","source_id":123},
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-28 22:06:00","type":"1","source_id":123}
]
```

есть json как посчитать одинаковые поля убрать их и отправить 5 параметром количество одинаковых параметров
За любую идею буду благодарен
json нужен для постройки графика на amcharts 4

Пример

```
 [
    {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27 21:05:11","type":"1","source_id":125,"total":1},
    {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27,"type":"1","source_id":125,"total":4}
 ]
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос желаемый результат.

Comment: Создать класс и сериализовать его. Либо добавить функцию для обработки данных

Comment: По какому полю хотите группировать?

Comment: по source id чтоб у него было уникальность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let mass = [
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27 21:05:11","type":"1","source_id":123},
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27 21:07:37","type":"1","source_id":135},
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-27 22:03:33","type":"1","source_id":123},
  {"ip":"123","data":"2019-02-28 22:06:00","type":"1","source_id":123}
]

console.log(group(mass));

function group(arr)
{
let res = [];
arr.forEach(el => {
   if (res.length === 0) 
   {
      el.total = 1;
      res.push(el);
   }
   else {
      res.every(elem => {
        if (el.source_id === elem.source_id)
        {
          elem.total++;
          return;
        }
        else {
          el.total = 1;
          res.push(el);
        }
      });
   }
});
return res;
}
//console.log(res);
```